# How to mark redundant non null assertion on Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I have added this wrapper ([source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41179#issuecomment-1920177478)) to the project I'm working on:

```js
export function expectToBeDefined<T>(
  arg: T,
): asserts arg is Exclude<T, undefined> {
  expect(arg).toBeDefined();
}
```

The goal is to avoid using non-null assertions in my tests like this.

```js
type User = {id?: string, name: string}
const user: User| null = await createTestUser()
const post: Post | null = await createTestPost(user?.id!)
```

I know that having the optional `id` doesn't make sense but I can't change it.

Once I add the new expect helper, I can eliminate the non-null assertion.

```js
const user: User| null = await createTestUser()
expectToBeDefined(user?.id)
const post: Post | null = await createTestPost(user.id)
```

I would like to know if there is an ESlint rule or plugin to highlight and possibly remove all the redundant non-null assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) has a [no-unnecessary-type-assertion](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-type-assertion) rule that should achieve what you want.

```js
const foo = 3;
// This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression
const bar = foo!;
```

[Playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tiacTJTIAhtEK0ipWkOTJE0fJQ5N0UOdA7RI4MAF8QOoA&code=MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDMBuAUKSsBGAhgE4ryICEGQA)

Comment: I think you should elaborate and maybe give an example to how it solves the problem